# Make the footer of the page load asynchronously

Tags: jquery, performance, load, opencart, footer

Is it possible to make footer of opencart load http://buydatabaseonline.com/demo/index.php asynchronously in order to make the website load faster?
I know it can be done by jQuery, but how can I make the entire code in footer's div load after the user reach the bottom of the page, like in Facebook?

---

To be more specific, take a look at http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=Vertex; when you scroll down, it loads other contents. I want some help on how I can integrate similar thing for footer.tpl in opencart template.

Comment: The technique you are looking for is called Lazy Loading.

Comment: @EricHerlitz or in this case its a kind of Infinite Scrolling or waypoints http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: thank you for your replies, but i think lazy loading is for pictures,it's the same idea but i need it for the entire div.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is totally new and OC has no option of doing it straight away. What You are looking for is:

- new controller, let's say `ControllerCommonFooterLazyLoading` in the folder `catalog/controller/common/`
- actions in this controller that will be called by AJAX requests, e.g. `loadInformationExcerpts`, `loadLatestReviews`, etc.
- view templates for each of the action
- optionally language file for new language token-string pairs
- optionally a model for Your new SQL queries

The basic presumption is understanding how the content lazy-loading is done (use Google if not). In Your footer template do place Your marks for lazy loading and after the concrete mark is visible, trigger the AJAX request for URL like

```
'index.php?route=common/footer_lazy_loading/load_latest_reviews'
```

The AJAX request will return compiled and parsed template which You can then place (append/prepend) into the DOM.

With a little work should be fairly easy to achieve...